# Binomial distribution vs markov chain

Tags: markov-chains, binomial-distribution

It seems like the binomial distribution and a markov chain where you move "up 1" with prob P and "down 1" with prob (1-P) are quite related.

[image]

**Does anyone know the formal relationship?**

To be more specific if you have n trials in a binomial distribution (equivalent to n states in the markov chain), the markov state distribution appears to be the same as the binomial distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Markov chain most closely linked to the binomial distribution is one where the particle moves up with probability $p$ and stays in place with probability $1-p$. Then after $n$ steps of this chain started at $0$, the distribution attained is precisely the Binomial$(n,p)$ distribution.

If $X_n$ denotes the state of this chain (started from $0$) after n steps, then the state of your chain (started from $0$) after $n$ steps is $2X_n-n$.